# Change drop down menu position

Tags: css, responsive-design, html-lists

I am wondering how to changes the location of my dropdown menu when the site is in its smallest size.
When www.whnetv.com is viewed on a computer or tablet the dropdown for channels is located where it should be. But on a iphone or the smallest browser window, the dropdown options show up to the left of the menu.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The CSS for you menu unordered list, `<ul>`, has absolute positioning based on its parent.

```
#menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    left: auto;
    z-index: 99999;
    background-color: #444;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

You will need to change this positioning based on the size of the screen detected, using something that makes your page responsive like media queries:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: i have a media queries in the css for the drop down.  I add the css above to it it doesn't make a difference . i also though that it the code was ablove where the media queries begin, it was global for all browser sizes. I have added the same code to the media top of the media querie as i am unsure what to change. Thanks

Comment: it seems like the dropdown stick to the menu bar not the specific button.

Comment: you change the "top" and "left" properties based on screen size.. if it's smaller, you want to reposition the dropdown under the new spot that channels is in.

Comment: How does this work with two drop down. i got it centered in the menu section but the dropdown covers the button. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what button you're referring to.  I visited your site, and saw the change, it looks like your "channels" dropdown is now in the desired position to me.

Comment: Please upvote my answer if this has helped you solve your problem